# VBA - save file as PDF to specific location with pre-defined name

Tags: excel, vba

Below code works fine until generate a filename. It picks up the correct folder location, but the file name is blank.[image]

If I choose location somewhere on my local machine, the filename appears then. Could you advise me what should I do differently, please?

```
Private Sub CBSaveasPDF_Click()
    Dim FileAndLocation As Variant
    Dim strPathLocation As String
    Dim strFilename As String
    Dim strPathFile As String        


    strPathLocation = "http://teams.xxx.intranet/sites/bipm/test/test/test/test/test/"
    strFilename = Me.Range("D8") & " -" & Me.Range("D7") & " -" & Me.Range("J7") & " " & Me.Range("B3")
    strPathFile = strPathLocation & strFilename

    FileAndLocation = Application.GetSaveAsFilename _
                        (InitialFileName:=strPathLocation & strFilename, _
                        filefilter:="PDF Files (*.pdf), *.pdf", _
                        Title:="Select Folder and FileName to save")
        If FileAndLocation = "False" Then
            MsgBox ("Document not saved")
            Exit Sub
        End If

        Me.ExportAsFixedFormat _
            Type:=xlTypePDF, _
            Filename:=strFilename, _
            Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
            IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
            IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
            OpenAfterPublish:=True
```

Comment: You need a backslash between your path and filename.

Comment: thanks @braX, I've tried that with or without backslash, but it still shows blank filename.

Comment: and what happens if you add `MsgBox strFilename` after you set the filename?

Comment: It shows the correct filename, but in the save pop-up box, it doesn't.

Comment: It looks like your code is written for a worksheet module.  This is silly, but you may want to verify your code is in the *right* worksheet module and that the cells holding your filename are in the same worksheet.

Comment: What is the exact value that you see if you do `MsgBox strPathLocation & strFilename`? Hope it looks like **"C:\SomeFolder\SomeFile.Pdf"**?

Comment: Also later you may want to change `Filename:=strFilename, _` to `Filename:=FileAndLocation, _` to ensure that it saves at a location chosen by the user (*in case the user changes directory*)

Comment: What is the value of `Me.Range("B3")` when you execute this code?